# Wedge product of $1-$forms and $2-$forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, exterior-algebra

I need to prove the following:

Let $\omega$ be a non-vanishing $1-$form on a smooth manifold $M$ such that $d\omega\wedge\omega=0.$ Show that there exists a $1-$form $\theta$ such that $d\omega=\theta\wedge\omega.$

The idea I have is write locally $\omega$ in terms of the canonical basis
$$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n a_idx_i,$$
where $n=\dim M$ and $a_i\in C^{\infty}(M).$ Then, 
$$d\omega=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}dx_j\wedge x_i$$
and
$$d\omega\wedge\omega=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_k\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}dx_k\wedge dx_j\wedge dx_i=0.$$
I'm stuck in this part because I don't know how to justify the existence of a local $1-$form $\theta_U.$ I think that if I prove this in open subsets $U$, then it would be easy extend it to the whole manifold by using partition of unity.

How can I construct $\theta$? I have tried to obtain inspiration by studying particular examples, but not even that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yikes! NO, don't resort to the canonical basis. (This would only work locally, anyhow.) Forget for a moment that we're talking about $d\omega$. Suppose you have a $2$-form $\phi$ so that $\phi\wedge\omega = 0$ and you want to show that $\phi = \theta\wedge\omega$ for some $1$-form $\theta$. Here's the main hint: Suppose you can extend $\omega=\omega_1$ to a basis $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_n$ for the $1$-forms on $M$. Write $\phi$ in terms of this basis. Can you get it now?

Now, in general, you can do this locally. Do you know a technique to turn local solutions into global ones?

Comment: We can extend $\omega$ to a basis because it's non-vanishing. Then I can write $\phi=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}\omega_i\wedge\omega_j.$ But I don't know where can I use the fact that $\phi\wedge\omega=0$

Comment: Well, first of all, make that sum over $i<j$, so you'll have a unique such representation. Now wedge that equation with $\omega$ and use what you know about what forms a basis for $\Lambda^3$.

Comment: I wrote $\phi=\sum_{i<j} (a_{ij}-a_{ji})\omega_i\wedge\omega_j.$ Then $0=\phi\wedge\omega=\sum_{i<j} (a_{ij}-a_{ji})\omega_i\wedge\omega_j\wedge\omega.$ This implies for $2\leq i<j$ and linear independence that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}.$ Then $a_{ij}\omega_i\wedge\omega_j+a_{ji}\omega_j\wedge\omega_i=0.$ This shows that in the expansion of $\phi$ it only appears $\omega$ wedge some other vector $\omega_k$ of the basis. Thus $\phi$ is of the form $\phi=\sum_{k=2}^n \alpha_k\omega_k\wedge\omega$ for some smooth functions $\alpha_k\in C^{\infty}(M).$ Am I right?

Comment: First, just make your life simple and write $\phi = \sum_{i<j} a_{ij}\omega_i\wedge\omega_j$. Try simplifying the argument with that. The point should be, as you observed, that to get $\phi\wedge\omega=0$, you cannot have any nonzero $a_{ij}$ with $i\ge 2$. This means you get the expression you claimed, yes.

Comment: BTW, @mathj, when you're satisfied with the answer, you should accept it, so that this question doesn't stay on the "unanswered" list. :)